# Trying to figure out what code I can add to make the first part of this jquery accordion open on load?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

This is the attached javascript, not sure how to have the first part open on load.  I have researched answers that mention adding a trigger class but not sure where to add it.

```
//Java Script
function initMenu() {
$('.accordion div').hide();
$('.accordion h3').click(
function() {
$(this).next().slideToggle('normal');
}
);
}
$(document).ready(function() {initMenu();});
```

html layout of accordion:

```
<div class="accordion">
 <h3>title</h3>
 <div>content</div>
 <h3>title</h3>
 <div>content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".accordion div").first().show()
```

Comment: How do I add this to the existing javascript?

Comment: Copy and paste it into the end of the initMenu() function?